# jquery drop down not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to use http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-dropdown/ for a simple drop down menu but for some reason, I cannot get it to work.

```
<a href="#" data-dropdown="#dropdown-1">dropdown</a>

<div id="dropdown-1" class="dropdown dropdown-tip">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#1">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#2">Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#3">Item 3</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown-divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#4">Item 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#5">Item 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#5">Item 6</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ywWjE/

What am I doing wrong? It's probably something really simple but I'm just not seeing it.

Comment: Start by including jQuery in your fiddle, then write some code, and hopefully once you're done it will do whatever it is you're trying to do.

Comment: There's no javascript in this?  how were you planning to manage the drop down?

Comment: for starters, your jsfiddle is missing jQuery

Comment: Oooh, smarty pants added everything as external resources in the fiddle. Remove jQuery as an external resource, and use the dropdown menu to select jQuery instead.

Comment: @adeneo http://jsfiddle.net/ywWjE/4/

Comment: Just include the files properly -> http://jsfiddle.net/ywWjE/8/

Comment: @adeneo so the issue lied in using github, strange.

Comment: It's not strange at all, github is not a CDN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your files from github weren't getting included properly in the fiddle. I copied pasted the JS and CSS in the fiddle and it works fine. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ywWjE/6/) is the working fiddle.

```
enter code here
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this `Fork`:- http://jsfiddle.net/KHteX/

Just include styles in the styles box in the fiddle and you should see it coming up.